# Levels Not Unlocking In Runner 2

Tags: runner2

So, I got to world 4. But when I neared the end, the levels quit unlocking. Anyone else having this problem, or does anyone at least know what's going on, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect more gold if you want to move forward.